# Removing [object%20PointerEvent] from my JavaScript variable when used in a source

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener, src

So basically in the bellow code I want to access the image which is related to the index of the array. Now on the console.log(i), I get "1" as there are two elements in the array.

However, when I click the "array" I get "../[object%20PointerEvent]1.png". This causes an error as the file name is 1.png not the above.

Does anyone know how I can remove the [object%20PointerEvent] so I just have the "../1.png"?

Thank you

```js
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    array[i].addEventListener("click", function nextImage(i) {
        image.src = i +".png";
    });
}
```

Comment: `function nextImage(i) ` why using **i** again here? change it to `function nextImage(event) `

Comment: basically I have an multiple windows in which I have a list of pictures I want the user to be able to navigate through. So instead of having to write out code for each individual window and picture. I'm wanting to use the index of the arrays to be able to change the image in the window for the specific arrow. Do let me know as it might not make sense, but if you look at the site im working on, imagine that there's more than one set of pictures (https://zsigmondkn.github.io/Main-Site/HTML/index.html)

Comment: I did find a workaround which is to "let t = i" and use the t instead of the i here ->"image.src = t +".png";" that way it loses the [object%20PointerEvent] and gives me the correct source of "1.png". But as I said it's a workaround and it would be nice to know if there's a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different variables named `i`.

- The one defined in the `for` loop that you **want**
- The parameter in your callback function which is passed the [Event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) that you **get**

Rename the second one so you stop [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the first one. Traditional names are `e` or `event` but since you aren't using it, you could just remove it.

Using a tool like eslint with the [no-shadow rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow) could have caught this error for you.

Answer (score 0):

The value passed into the object will automatically be the event and not the value from the array. A better way of doing this is:

```
array[i].addEventListener("click", function nextImage(a){return (event)=>{
        image.src = a +".png"}
        }(i)
    );
```

Comment: Now we have (and the OP is using) `let`, there's no need to use an IIFE to hack the scope like that.

Comment: Thank you for your input, it also helped me to visualise how I can do it. Thank you